# Acceso a objeto de clase con instanceof

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

Quiero entender bien porque si tengo lo siguiente,no consigo que me funcione el instanceof dentro del if.

Tengo una lista de empleados que recorro con un for,cada empleado puede ser o medico o enfermero y dentro de enfermero tengo auxiliar de enfermeria.

```
public abstract class empleado{
//..
}

public class medico extends empleado {
//..
}

public class enfermero extends empleado{
//..
}

public class auxiliar extends enfermero{
//..
}
```

Ahora recorro la lista de empleados y en funcion de si es un medico,enfermero o auxiliar hago una cosa...

```
for(int i=0;i<empleados.size();i++){

if(empleados.get(i) instanceof medico){
}else 
if(empleados.get(i) instanceof enfermero){
}else {
(empleado.get(i) instanceof auxiliar)
}
```

El problema es que no diferencia entre enfermero y auxiliar...Si tengo 3 enfermeros y 2 auxiliares,a los auxiliares los toma como enfermerosxque es cierto,pero el tipo auxiliar no lo coge...

Este problema como puedo solucionarlo o a que se debe.

}

Comment: El problema es que ***un `auxiliar` SIEMPRE va a ser un `enfermero`***, puesto que eso es lo que define a la herencia. Tu clase siempre va a poder ser tratada como la clase padre, es decir, es perfectamente válido hacer `private enfermero enfermero1 = new auxiliar();`, puesto que el auxiliar es también enfermero... por eso cuando compruebas si es `instanceof enfermero` entra al if, puesto que... si, es un enfermero también! Debes invertir esa cláusula y comprobar primero si es un `auxiliar`, y luego `enfermero`, así te funcionará correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es invertir el orden de los **if** e ir del tipo más específico al más general:

```
for(int i = 0; i < empleados.size(); i++)
{
   if(empleados.get(i) instanceof medico)
   {
   }
   else if(empleados.get(i) instanceof auxiliar)
   {
   }
   else if(empleado.get(i) instanceof enfermero )
   {
   }   
}
```

Como ves debes invertir los **if**, y primero preguntas por la clase más especializada que en este caso es auxiliar y después por la más general que es enfermero.